# Spark - several values should be written once in the schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have the following schema:

```
<record>
 <long name="update"/>
 <string name="dc"/>
 <array name="clients">
   <record>
     <string name="ip"/>
     <array name="client_ids">
         <string name="client_id"/>
     </array>
   </record>
</record>
```

Now, the clients column is being calculated using a distributed query with several shuffle partitions. The result should be 1 file containing the information, and in it "update" and "dc" should appear only once, **and not on every row.**

What I tried was:

```
 val rdd = sql.sql(s"query to generate the clients column")
.map(some_adjustments)
.repartition(1)
.mapPartitions { rowsIt =>
    val clients = rowsIt.toArray 
    val result = mutable.WrappedArray.make[Row](Array(Row(update, dc,mutable.WrappedArray.make[Row](clients))))

    result.iterator
}
```

So this works, but results in OutOfMemory, probably due to the rowsIt.toArray.
Doing the same repartition(1) but having the update/dc duplicated on each row runs smoothly.

Comment: `.repartition(1)`  + `val clients = rowsIt.toArray ` collects all data in memory. If it cannot fit in memory, a whole thing will crash.

Comment: which is what's happening like I wrote. I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?